# Animating sticky navigation?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to animate a sticky navigation - what I want to do is make it bounce in smoothly. How can I do that?

I have the following .js script:

```
    var  mn = $(".menu");
    mns = "menu-scrolled";
    hdr = $('.menu').height() + $('.navigation').height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
        mn.addClass(mns);
      } else {
        mn.removeClass(mns);
      }
    });
```

I'm using the following code as a reference: http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgYOg  Check this out you can animate the  height.

Comment: What do you mean by "bounce in smoothly"?

Answer (score 1):

We can use css animations to animate the `top` property of the nav:

```
.main-nav-scrolled {
   -webkit-animation:bounce 0.5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    top: -200px;  
  }
  to {
    top: 0; 
  }
}
```

Whenever the `.main-nav-scrolled` class is added through javascript the the nav will slide down smoothly.

Keep in mind the browser prefixes too.

**[example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/RPKjdN)**